# Dates between dates in table given different content

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have a scenario whereby I need to see if a date falls between a start date and an end date, then every table cell between those dates I need to fill with a word like continue (See picture below for example).

[image: Current table layout]

Pulling the data from the database and then comparing the start dates and end dates against an of array dates I am able to populate a table like the above image. The complications begin to arise when I try to add information to the cells between looping.

I used:

```
if(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($test->range[$i])) > $data['sData'] && date("Y-m-d", strtotime($test->range[$i])) > $data['eData']){
    echo "<td class='col-md-6'>Continue</td>";
}
```

However, this didn't provide the output I was after.

My current code is:

```
$all = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `assignment` WHERE user_id = $user ORDER BY `sDate` ASC");
$all->execute();
$rows = $all->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);


echo "<table class='table table-hover'><tr><td></td>";
for($i = 0; $i < count($test->range); $i++){

    echo "<td class='col-md-6'>" . date("d-m-Y", strtotime($test->range[$i])) . "</td>";

}

echo "</tr>";

foreach($rows as $data){
    echo "<tr><td>" . $data['name'] . "</td>";
    for($i = 0; $i < count($test->range); $i++){
        if($data['sDate'] === date("Y-m-d", strtotime($test->range[$i]))){
            echo "<td class='col-md-6'>Start</td>";
        }
        if(date("Y-m-d", strtotime($test->range[$i])) > $data['sData'] && date("Y-m-d", strtotime($test->range[$i])) > $data['eData']){
            echo "<td class='col-md-6'>Continue</td>";
        }

        if($data['eDate'] === date("Y-m-d", strtotime($test->range[$i]))){
            echo "<td class='col-md-6'>End</td>";
        }
        echo "<td class='col-md-6'></td>";
    }
}

echo "</table>"
```

**How can I fill the table cells between start and end with the word continue?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a helper variable?

```
foreach($rows as $data){
    echo "<tr><td>" . $data['name'] . "</td>";
    $started = false;
    for($i = 0; $i < count($test->range); $i++){
        if($data['sDate'] === date("Y-m-d", strtotime($test->range[$i]))){
            echo "<td class='col-md-6'>Start</td>";
            $started = true;
        }

        if($data['eDate'] === date("Y-m-d", strtotime($test->range[$i]))){
            echo "<td class='col-md-6'>End</td>";
            $started = false;
        }

        if($started){
            echo "<td class='col-md-6'>Continue</td>";
        }
        echo "<td class='col-md-6'></td>";
    }
}
```